# Writing to file for mac and windows with java

Tags: java, file, system, separator

I have a problem when writing to file in windows. My JAVA program works just fine in my Mac, but in windows it just doesn't work.

This is the code that executes differently in windows:

```
String string = textArea.getText();

if (string.contains(System.getProperty("line.separator"))) {
    notatet = string.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "<line.separator>");
}
```

When I save this string to a txt file in MAC I get this:

```
Line1<line.separator>Line2<line.separator><line.separator>Line3
```

But when I save this string to txt file in WINDOWS i get this:

```
Line1
Line2

Line3
```

Now I obviuosly want the Mac option, that is my target. What should I do with my code to make it work in both/all operating systems?

Comment: Side note: you have `System.lineSeparator()` from java 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29

Comment: None of the above. Avoid hard-coding special characters, and use `println()`. It knows what the system line separator is.

Comment: `line.separator` on windows is `\r\n`. Check your text area to see if it really contians this separator and not only `\n`

Comment: @jhamon I have checked it and it really contains this separator.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Can this be because java is not updated on my windows?

Comment: Nope. The property dates back to older java versions, the mehtod is relatively new.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you maybe have `\r\n` or have `\n` as line seperator in your string. Which is not matched from your if statement. Simply use an regex and the replaceAll Methode.

See following Example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String string = "Test\ntest\r\ntest";
        String n = string.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "<line.separator>");
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Output:
Testtesttest

[Running Example](http://ideone.com/i3Beym)

### EDIT

For the case `Test\n\ntest\r\ntest` the code above works not correctly.
Replace the line with the regex with the following lines:

```
    String n = string.replaceAll("\\n", "<line.separator>");
    n = n.replaceAll("\\r", "");
```

So if more than one `\r\n` or `\n`appear the replacement will work correctly.
Because all cases contains `\n` these are first replaced with the `<line.separator>` after that the line `n.replaceAll("\\r", "");` made a clean up and removes the unnecessary `\r`.

Comment: When I test this I only get one problem.. If I have double \n it only detects it as one. If the string is `"Test\n\ntest\r\ntest"`, I still get; `Test<line.separator>test<line.separator>test`.. NOT; `Test<line.separator><line.separator>test<line.separator>test`, which it should be

Comment: But if i remove the `+` from the regex it works as I intened, to detect multiple line breaks. Is removing the `+` the right way to get this?

Comment: No the problem is that you get also for `\r\n` two lineseperators, which is wrong. But i have another solution. See my edit answer

Comment: @Zelldon, your edited answer will not work for a string like `"Test\rTest"` and only print `TestTest`

Comment: Yes 'cause \r is not valid line break \r\n or \n will be only a valid line seperator

Comment: @Zelldon What happens if I remove the + sign? Seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @Zelldon, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline and http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-32.html
`java.util.regex.Pattern` defines the `\R` as "Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`"

Comment: @nyname00 thanks you're right http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html also says XML Schema and XPath also treat the carriage return \r as a line break character. JavaScript adds the Unicode line separator \u2028 and page separator \u2029 on top of that. But he work Java on Mac or Win so only `\r\n` and `\n` will appear. But your solution is very nice i will vote for you.

Comment: @Zelldon So this, `[\\r\\n]` will work for me? Or will removing the + cause trouble?

Comment: @Peter like i sad if you remove the plus sign `\r` and `\n` are replaced separately, which means `\r\n` will cause two `<line.separator><line.separator>` either use my second solution or nyname00 's cleaner solution. If you dont care that these `\r\n` will cause two replacements than you can remove simply the plus sign.

Comment: @Zelldon Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's the easy to use `Linebreak matcher` `\R` which should take care of all the various `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n` combinations.

```
String text = "A\r\nB\n\nC\rD\rE\r\rF";
String res = text.replaceAll("\\R", "<line.separator>");
System.out.println(res);
```

will print

```
A<line.separator>B<line.separator><line.separator>C<line.separator>D<line.separator>E<line.separator><line.separator>F
```

and should work on every OS.

**Edit**: `\R` is new with Java 8. You can use 
`\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` for older versions.

```
String res = text.replaceAll("\\u000D\\u000A|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]",
    "<line.separator>");
```

Comment: I get this error `illegal/unsupported escape sequence`. On the `"\\R"`. Why is that?

Comment: Will `Pattern.quote("\\R")` do the same job?

Comment: @Peter, I guess you're working on JVM 1.7 or lower. \R is new with 1.8.  the regex I posted in reply to Zelldon should be equivalent and work with older JVMs

Comment: Here it is again `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

Comment: So `string = string.replaceAll("\\u000D\\u000A|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]", "<line.separator>");` will work exactly the same?

Comment: Yep, that will lead to the same results (taken from here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)